# Toolbar button goes out of viewport in sencha

Tags: html, css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a toolbar with few buttons right aligned. But when i add some lengthy html content the buttons go out of viewport.

```
Ext.define('Project.view.ContainerPanel',{
extend:'Ext.Panel',
requires:['Ext.Panel'],
xtype:'containerPanel', 
config:
{
    items:[
           {
                xtype:'toolbar',
                title:'Content',
                height:46,
                ui:'dark',
                docked:'top',
                items:[
                       {
                           xtype:'button',
                           text:'Back',
                           ui:'back'
                       },
                      {
                           xtype:'spacer'
                       },
                       {
                           xtype:'button',
                           text:"left",
                           ui:'normal',
                       },
                       {
                           xtype:'spacer',
                           width:1
                       },
                       {
                           html:'Page',
                           ui:'normal',
                           height:35
                       },
                       {
                           xtype:'spacer',
                           width:1

                       },
                       {
                           xtype:'button',
                           text:"right",
                           ui:'normal',
                       },

                       ]
            },

            {
                     xtype:'panel',
                     items:[
                            {
                                 html:'<div id="msg"></div><div id="view">Huge content without break -> dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>',
                            }

                            ]

            }, 

        ]

 }
});
```

How to fit all the buttons within the toolbar? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below line to config solved the problem.

```
 layout:'fit',
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar headaches trying to get my title bar looking right and all I have really found is to keep it bare. I try not to put any more that 2 buttons in my toolbar, one of which  typically displays a menu. I kind of tore up your view but here's an example: [Fiddle Example](http://new.senchafiddle.com/#A0Wou/).